# React security: state manipulation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, security, recaptcha, states

I am developing a React project, and love how dynamic it can be.  However, when dealing with dynamic security features - in my case, a Google reCAPTCHA, I am getting quite worried about the possibility of users manipulating my states and properties.

For instance, this is how I handle reCAPTCHA:

```
class Create extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.onRECAPTCHA = this.onRECAPTCHA.bind(this);
    this.state = {captcha: false}
    // ...
  }

  onRECAPTCHA(value) {
    if (value == null) {
      this.setState({captcha: false})
    }
    this.setState({captcha: true})
  }
}
```

I have a handler for a button onClick, which in the function, tests against this.state.captcha before proceeding.  It works as intended, but I stumbled upon react-dev-tools and found that I was able to manually manipulate my captcha state!  Am I blatantly missing something, or should I not be setting captcha as a state/property?  This concerns me about several other states/props I have set as well.  All of my validation is stored this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, you'll need authorization to take place in a secured setting, and the browser isn't that place. If you're guarding a form submittal, for example, it's up to you to have the server-side code that processes the submittal to validate that the captcha response is as expected. The fact that client-side state can be manipulated shouldn't really matter as long as you're not using that as your sole source of validation/authorization.

Comment: My captcha does get validated over the server, but I store its result in the client, giving a window of opportunity for a person to manipulate the state.  I don't know how to deal with this as a client because most of the time, you click "I'm not a robot" before you click "Submit" - so that window seems like it should be everywhere.

Comment: The server should be validating the captcha along with the form submittal. You don't want the client to control the (final) validation state.

Comment: But how does that explain the existence of a Submit button?  If I were to handle everything directly from server validation, as soon as they clicked "Im not a robot" I would submit the form (if validated).  What I'm getting confused about, is that state of existence in between checking that box and clicking submit.

Comment: My solution is to disable the submit button until server-side validation comes back.  In which that is only triggered by the server, not states.  Thanks for the perspective!

Comment: If you want to separate captcha verification from submit verification, then when your server validates the captcha, it should persist some sort of non-forgeable token as proof of validation and send it back to the client. When the client submits, it should send that token back to the server, so the server can verify it's an authorized request. Simply disabling the submit button isn't secure since the user can easily enable it with development tools. You could also just merge your captcha and submit verification.